# How to remove skybox in unity using C#

Tags: unity, skybox

How to change or remove Skybox on run time in unity using C#?

Is there any way to remove it while its not even required?

Or load it using http link for material we are using in Skybox.

Comment: i didnt see that post so thats why posting it over here.

Comment: @MaazIrfan I would recommend to delete it on stackoverflow. Unity is used almost only for game development, so the question fits better here.

Comment: It's difficult to accept your claim of "i didnt see that post..." when it was posted from the same account. It was probably an honest mistake - own it, learn from it & move on to getting your question posted in the single SE site where it most belongs.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @pikalek will definitely follow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this under any function if you want to remove 
 for example in

```
void Update()
{ RenderSettings.skybox = (null);
```

or just use this RenderSetting.skybox = (null);

```
public material = skyboxMat;
```

to change skybox same  `RenderSetting.skybox = skyboxMat;` is being used

Answer (score 0):

In addition setting the skybox globally with [`RenderSettings.skybox = newMaterial`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderSettings-skybox.html), you can also set a skybox on the camera-level. This can be useful when you want to have different cameras with different skyboxes.

1. Add a [Skybox component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Skybox.html) to the camera game object
2. Refer to it with [`GetComponent<Skybox>().material = newMaterial`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Skybox-material.html)